# Unit Test Expo-Google-Sign-In using Jest in Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, expo, google-signin

I am trying to unit test below piece of code in expo react-native using jest but it gives error of undefined. Below is the function

```
import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in'

signInAsync = async () => {
  try {
    await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync()
    const result = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync()
    return result
  } catch ({ message }) {
    return { type: 'failure', message }
  }
}
```

Error is highlighted in import. I do understand that expo-google-sign-in doesnt work on expo client app rather it works in a standalone app. Do same thing applies for unit test as well? Can we mock this call to GoogleSignIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer which is working fine

```
describe('Google Services', () => {
  describe('signInAsync', () => {
    it('Calling on signInAsync', async () => {
      const response = await GoogleService.signInAsync()
      expect(response).toEqual({
        type: 'success',
        token: 'googleToken',
      })
    })
  })
```